# Who wants which gifts in the Witcher

Tags: the-witcher

I want to know which gifts I should hang on to and, by exclusion, which gifts can be sold to merchants without fear of having to re-buy them to appease that one snotty NPC.

So far I've seen the following:

**1st act**

- Trish: **Trish's potion** (obvs)
- (Buxom) peasant woman in the village on the outskirts of Vizima:
  **Tulips** (A corpse in the area will have them). Reward: good time.
- Beggar woman living in the village on the outskirts of Vizima: **White Gull**, will reward with **Eternal Fire signet ring**.
- Old woman living in the village on the outskirts of Vizima who doesn't talk to strangers: Unknown, will accept bribe. Rewards with a story.
- Woman in white dress living in a house on the outskirts of Vizima:
  **Wild flowers**, will give **Tulips** as reward.
- Old woman living in the house opposite of the chapel: Any **food** (Bread
  is most cost-effective), will tell a story, possibly giving some
  glossary entries.
- Vesna, after completing her quest, at the mill: any **wine**. Reward: good time.

**Act2**

- Jethro, at the dungeon: **Fisstech**, rewards with information. useless unless part of a quest.
- Gardener at Vizima's temple: any **food**, will reward with a tale or roses of any color you choose. Repeatble.
- Herbalist at the market of Vizima's Temple district: **Red shawl**. Reward: information about where she gathers herbs. useless.
- Bootblack, near where you emerge from the sewers in Vizima: **Shadow People, or the story of His Majesty's Secret Service**. Get the book by outdrinking Thaler. Reward: **Prophet Lebioda's signet ring**, useful for getting past Shani's landlady.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best resource for this is the [Shopping List](https://witcher.fandom.com/wiki/The_Witcher_Shopping_List) over at the Witcher Wikia.

The 'condensed version', totaling up all of the various by chapter lists, provides these aggregate numbers:

> - **40** Beer, **1** Wine, **1** Rose Wine, **5** Sodden Mead, & **3** Temerian Rye
> - **20** of any food item. In addition, you'll need **5** Bread, **1** Dried Nuts, and **2** Sugardolls
> - **1** Daisy, **1** White Roses, **1** Red Roses, **1** Tulips, and **1** of any kind of flowers.
> - **1** Lady's Shawl, **2** Gold Shawls, **2** Red Shawls, and **2** Red Gloves.
> - **1** Amber, **1** Ruby, **2** Diamonds, **2** Sapphires, and **1** of any precious gem.
> - **1** Silver Amber or Silver Ruby ring. Which depends on one of the major choices you'll make in Chapter 3. Additionally, **1**  of any kind of ring.
> - **5** Beggartick, **5** Celandine, **5** White Myrtle, **6** Fool's Parsley, and **1** each of Feainnewedd, Honeysuckle, Naezan Salts, and a Wine Stone.
> - **1** Red Meteorite
> - **2** Fisstech
> - **1** Perfume, **1** Swallow, **1** White Honey, **1** White Raffard's Decoction, and **2** White Gull.
>
> And finally, for skinnable items, you'll need
>
> - **3** Alghoul Marrow, **6** Alp Fangs, **3** Archespore Juice, **11** Barghest Skulls, **3** Basilisk Hide, **10** Bloedzuiger Blood, **6** Bruxa Blood, **6** Cemtaur Jaws, **5** Cockatrice Feathers, **4** Death Dust, **6** Dog Tallow, **10** Drowned Dead Tongues, **3** Drowner Brains, **11** Devourer Teeth, **3** Echinops Roots, **3** Fleder Fangs, **2** Garkain Saliva, **15** Ghoul Blood, **4** Giant Centipede Armor, **5** Gravier Bones, **11** Kikimore Claws, **9**, Shadow Dust *or* Shimmering Dust, **11** Wolf Pelts, **3** Wyvern Eggs, **10** Wyvern Steaks

If it's not listed above, or you've already made use of one, and you don't have a use for it yourself, you can safely sell it. Consult the Shopping List link above for a more detailed chapter by chapter breakdown of which items are useful where and when.

Comment: Dead link. Shopping list is [moved to a new URL](https://witcher.fandom.com/wiki/The_Witcher_Shopping_List).

Answer (score 4):

As you said **Trish's potion**, **Tulips**, **White Gull**, **Wild flowers** and food(**bread**).

Chapter II

- Prostitutes - in the Temple Quarter will accept any flowers.
- Gossip - in the Temple Quarter during the day near
  the Hospital or the detective's house. Give her **Gold Woman's Gloves**,
  **Red Woman's Gloves**, or a **Diamond**. You'll probably have to talk to her
  several times before you have the opportunity to give her a gift.
- Declan Leuvaarden on the Dike give him **3 Salamander Brooch** to prove your loyalty and receive 600 orens.

Chapter III

- Couresan - She's outside the New Narakort Inn. Pay her with orens or a gem (an **Amber** will do)
- Blue-eyed Lass - She can be found in the House of the Queen of the Night. Give her 500 orens (300 if you show her the **House of the Night Signet Ring**) or a **Sapphire**.
- Townclerk - on the second floor of Town Hall in the Trade Quarter will fool around with you if you call her a naughty girl and give her a **Diamond**.
- Noblewoman dressed all in white in the Trade Quarter near the Town Hall will sleep with you if you give her a **Silk Scarf**.
- Noblewoman near Triss' House in the Trade Quarter will sleep with you for a **Kikimore Claw**.
- Celina - Give her **any ring** and she'll sleep with you
- Peasant Women - You'll find her in the Inn or wandering around the Village. Give her a **Sugardoll** and she'll sleep with you.
- Elf Woman inside the Elven Cave by the Lakeside will sleep with you if you give her **food** after completing the Daily Bread quest.

This are just some of the things you can use mostly to get some "affection".The list is not 100% complete so unfortunately it doesn't give you good insight on what gifts to sell immediately.